# Physical to Physical Migration of server OS's and applications

Tags: windows-server-2003, vmware-converter, hardware, migration, hp-proliant

I have several physical servers which have windows 2003 OS'es installed on them along with a couple of web based applications running on them.

These servers are HP DL380 G5 servers which are coming to end of life and don't have such a good power usage as the more modern G6/G7 HP DL380 servers.

At the moment the estimated effort to migrate these OS'es and applications to new hardware is substantial so I'm looking for a tool similar to VMWare converter which does P2V to do P2P migrations.

I can stand the cost of some downtime on these servers if I can find a tool to do the migration for me and therefore save me many days human resource.

Can anyone advise of an appropriate tool and your experience with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Novell have a product called [PlateSpin PowerConvert](http://www.platespin.com/products/powerconvert/overview.aspx) that will do P2P, P2V and V2P reliably across a very wide range of platforms and operating systems. It's not cheap (list price is $200 per conversion) but it will do both hot (live, minimal downtime) and cold migrations.

You can prepare all of your migrations in advance, scanning both the source and target systems, defining the parameters for the migration and it will give you a very comprehensive analysis highlighting any issues that need to be resolved before you start.

Comment: I've used PlateSpin for P2V, it is a good product.

Answer (score 1):

I used Acronis True Image Workstation with the Universal Restore addon to do this, quite a lot, around 2006 onwards.  It worked very well, although I have not used it for some time.  I did use it again more recently, when I started getting into virtualisation, around three years ago.

True Image Workstation/Server is now called [Acronis® Backup & Recovery™ 10](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/server-windows/).  It's not cheap and the [Universal Restore](http://www.acronis.com/backup-recovery/server-windows/universal-restore.html) addon costs extra.

However, it is good, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

does clonezilla fit your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Check out Double-Take Move. That is a core functionality of the product.

http://www.doubletake.com/uk/products/double-take-move/Pages/default.aspx